# App with a module that contains a different targetSdkVersion that the app

Tags: android, module, dependencies

In my app I need execute one function with targetSdkVersion = 22, however I want that my app has targetSdkVersion = 24. My attempt was create a module that after I added as a dependency of my app, where these module has targetSdkVersion = 22. The problem is that when I run the function from my module, it runs with the target = 24.

EDIT: Maybe I may have explained badly. I want execute the same function for all sdk, but the function just runs correctly if I set my app targetSdkVersion to 22. Exists some way to do that, without creating one secundary app with the target = 22 and call it from my main app  ?

( I need targetSdkVersion = 22 to execute  this line: `Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "button_key_light", -1)` that just works well in Android 6 if the targetSdkVersion  of my app was <= 22;

Thank you

Comment: You can always have a `BUILD.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22` check in a conditional for assuring version compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In my app I need execute one function with targetSdkVersion = 22, however I want that my app has targetSdkVersion = 24

Sorry, that is not possible. `targetSdkVersion` is for the entire app. The `targetSdkVersion` that you provide in a module's will be overridden by the app's `targetSdkVersion` by default. You might be able to rig up rules to have the module's `targetSdkVersion` be the one that is used instead. But, in either case, the resulting value is used for the entire app, including your library module.

Comment: oh :( You know some way to execute this line of code on targetSdkVersion >= 23 : Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "button_key_light", -1) ??

Comment: @FayaX: No, sorry. I don't even know what `button_key_light` is.

Comment: is for turn off capacity button backlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this condition:

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22)

or you can also use this anotation at the begining of the function

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.X) (where X is the name of the version that you want)

Comment: Thak you for the response, but I edited my question. I may have explained badly.